# How do I bind data from SQL Server to an HTML page.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql-server, ajax

I want to bind/show data from sql server into a .html page by using javascript,AJAX,jquery but without using c#,php,vb.net etc.... can anyone plz help by posting some reference links or by posting the code itself..

Comment: what server language are you planning to use to communicate with SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with node.js

There are many examples out there, one of them:

http://blog.codeship.io/2014/04/22/leverage-sql-server-with-node-js-using-edge-js.html